# Install a color picker

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having trouble installing any color picker, I always end up falling at this site "gitbhu" but I do not know what to do with these files, from what I understand this is a project implemented already, but I need to download for later import in my project and use? I do not find the files. jar to import in eclipse, just Some files. java, can someone give me a walkthrough of how I install this or any other color picker? thank you!

https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the link you provide  isnt an eclipse addon but an application created to be a colorPicker that runs on android

to install a color picker for eclipse use [css designer](http://www.jointlogic.com/cssdesigner/download.vm)

personally i just use a webpage [color picker website](http://www.colorpicker.com/)

it gets the job done without all the unnecessary  instillation process

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need the color picker is available in android app, and not for me to use in eclipse, I want the User Application and choose a color it result can be stored in a variable.

Comment: in that case go into the source folder download the original java files in https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker/tree/master/src/com/larswerkman/holocolorpicker add them to your project and fix them as neccessery.or an easier thing to do is to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316831/how-to-add-color-picker-in-application and look at the answer